# Set DataGridView to full screen mode on C#

Tags: c#, grid, fullscreen

Is there any way to fix the DataGridView and its columns to full screen on C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set property **Anchor** of your GridView to *Top, Left* and choose *Fill* in the properties **AutoSizeColumnsMode** and **Dock**.